# Select one contact number from a list of multiple contact numbers

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to fetch only the first contact number from a list of contact numbers of a particular user, with the help of `cursor`. Here is my code:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getAllContacts() {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nameList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> person=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> number=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        if ((cur!=null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
            while (cur!=null && cur.moveToNext()) {

                String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                person.add(name);

                if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);

                    if(pCur.getCount()==1) {
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            number.add(phoneNo);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            temp.add(phoneNo);
                        }
                        number.add(temp.get(0));
                        temp.clear();
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (cur!=null) {
            cur.close();
        }
        Log.d("contacts",String.valueOf(number.size())+" "+String.valueOf(person.size())); //the lists aren't of equal size

        if(person.size()==number.size()){
            nameList.add(person);
            nameList.add(number);
        }
        else{
            //don't know what to do here
        }
        return nameList;

    }
```

But, the code still fetches multiple contact numbers saved for a single user, in other words `person.size()` is not equal to `number.size()`. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array sizes are not the same because not all contacts have phone-numbers, you are correctly checking for `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` and only if true, getting that contact's phone numbers - which means `number.size()` would be < `person.size()` on most phones.

I would suggest instead of keeping separate Arrays for names and phones, having a single Array with a simple java class that represents a person.

Other than that, your code is very inefficient, as you're doing a ton of queries, while you can do just one.

Here's an example with the two suggestions above:

```
class Person {
    long id,
    String name,
    String firstPhone;

    public Person(id, name, firstPhone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.firstPhone = firstPhone;
    }
}

Map<Long, Person> mapping = new HashMap<>(); // mapping between a contact-id to a Person object

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};

// query phones only
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1); // full name
    String phone = cur.getString(2); // phone

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + " - " + data);

    // only add a new object if we haven't seen this person before
    if (!mapping.containsKey(id)) {
        Person person = new Person(id, name, phone);
        mapping.put(id, person);
    }
}
cur.close();

Array<Person> people = mapping.values();
```

**EDIT**

```
Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();
Array<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
Array<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};

// query phones only
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1); // full name
    String phone = cur.getString(2); // phone

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + " - " + data);

    // only add a new object if we haven't seen this person before
    if (ids.add(id)) {
        names.add(name);
        numbers.add(phone);
    }
}
cur.close();
```

Comment: I want two seperate lists, where one contains the person's names, and the other contains their respective contact numbers. One person should have only one contact number. Actually I want to view only the contact's names in a listview, and when a particular name is pressed, then a text sms will be sent to its respective phone number

Comment: i would strongly advise not to have two different lists (for names and phones), but a single one holding some object, but if that's your thing, see my edit above